# Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.global.jdbc.deneme2DS

Tags: wildfly, datasource

DataSourceConfig.java

```
import jakarta.annotation.sql.DataSourceDefinition;

import jakarta.ejb.Singleton;


@Singleton

@DataSourceDefinition(

    name = "java:global/jdbc/deneme2DS",

    className = "org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource",

    url = "jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1",

    user = "sa",

    password = "sa"

)

public class DataSourceConfig {

    // This class can be empty, as it only serves to define the DataSource

    // The DataSource will be automatically registered when this class is loaded

}
```

persistence.xml

> <persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
>
> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>
> xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence
> [https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd"](https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd%22)
>
> version="3.0">
>
> ```
>   <!-- Use a portable JNDI name for the datasource -->
>
>   <jta-data-source>java:global/jdbc/deneme2DS</jta-data-source>
>
>   <properties>
>
>
>       <property
>
>           name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
>
>           value="drop-and-create" />
>
>       <property name="jakarta.persistence.sql-load-script-source"
>
>           value="import.sql" />
>
>       <!-- Properties for Hibernate <property name="hibernate.show_sql"
> ```
>
> value="false"
>
> ```
>           /> -->
>
>   </properties>
> ```

here is the error log

> 20:26:07,298 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation]
> (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed -
> address: ([("deployment" => "deneme2-ear.ear")]) - failure
> description: {
> "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.global.jdbc.deneme2DS"],
> "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
> "jboss.persistenceunit."deneme2-ear.ear/deneme2-ejb.jar#primary".**FIRST_PHASE**
> is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.global.jdbc.deneme2DS]",
> "jboss.persistenceunit."deneme2-ear.ear/deneme2-ejb.jar#primary" is
> missing [jboss.naming.context.java.global.jdbc.deneme2DS]"
> ] }

Same setup works for Payara but not for Wildfly so i'm suspecting it is a bug on Wildfly side, posting here to make sure there isn't something i have missed.

I'm using payara/server-full and jboss/wildfly docker images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to Wildfly 31 solved the problem it was a bug on old version.